# file to recall in other classes: how to do?

Tags: java, android

how do I make a file that I can recall in some classes without having to paste the same code each time? For example, I have to add this code to google analystics but since I do not want to paste the same code each time how can I create a file to recall in the other classes? The code is

```
@Override
      public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        EasyTracker.getInstance().setContext(this);
        EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(this);
    }

     @Override
      public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        EasyTracker.getInstance().setContext(this);
        EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStop(this);
      }
```

Comment: use the standard file with the above snippet as a parent class.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a static method and call it in each class

```
public static void onStart(MyInterface curclass)
{
    curclass.onStart();
    EasyTracker.getInstance().setContext(curclass);
    EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(curclass);
}

public static void onStop(MyInterface curclass) 
{
    curclass.onStop();
    EasyTracker.getInstance().setContext(curclass);
    EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStop(curclass);
  }
```

Keep in mind that the classes you call this on need to implement an interface with the method `onStart()` and `onStop()`.

Comment: you are using `this` in a static context

Answer (score 0):

Create a parent class:

```
public abstract class TrackedActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        EasyTracker.getInstance().setContext(this);
        EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        EasyTracker.getInstance().setContext(this);
        EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStop(this);
    }
}
```

And let the activities that you want to track extend this class (rather than `Activity`), so if you have

```
public MyActivity extends Activity {
    // ...
}
```

change this to

```
public MyActivity extends TrackedActivity {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: And if I import the class TrackedActivity is not the same thing?

Comment: @GiovanniM. No, importing by itself doesn't do anything.